# python - sort a list of list based on items from index 1 to the rest

Tags: python

Using Python 2

I have a list of list

```
list_of_list = [[a5, abc, xyz], [a1, abc, def],[a2, 4, 2, 3], [a3, 1, 2]]
```

I have to sort the list so all all the items that has numbers in the 2nd to later position comes after the items that has letter in those position.

The output should be

```
sorted_list = [[a1, abc, def], [a5, abc, xyz], [a3, 1, 2], [a2, 4, 2, 3]]
```

How do I do that? Using below code doesn't do it exactly as the sorting is not only based on the 2nd item in the inner list.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(list_of_list, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: [The Tutorial has a section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) that talks a bit about indices for strings which applies to lists also.  You may need to use a negative index.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the following tuple to get your desired result: `(x[1].isdigit(), x[1], x[0])`

```
l = sorted(list_of_list, key=lambda x: (x[1].isdigit(), x[1], x[0]))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['a1', 'abc', 'def'], ['a5', 'abc', 'xyz'], ['a3', '1', '2'], ['a2', '4', '2', '3']]
```